# Qt анимация цвета GroupBox

Tags: c++, qt, анимация, qpropertyanimation, qgroupbox

Необходимо реализовать анимацию смены цвета **QGroupBox**. Вот пример кода от какого-то чела, но такой вариант, как и все другие, не работает. Так-же когда должна произойти анимация, выводится вот это:
**"QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property color of your QObject"**

AnimatedBackground.h

```
#ifndef ANIMATEDBACKGROUND_H
#define ANIMATEDBACKGROUND_H

#include <QGroupBox>



сlass AnimatedBackground : public QGroupBox
{

  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor)

public:
  AnimatedBackground(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
  {
  }
  void setColor (QColor color){
    setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: rgb(%1, %2, %3);").arg(color.red()).arg(color.green()).arg(color.blue()));
  }
  QColor color(){
    return Qt::black;
  }
};

#endif // ANIMATEDBACKGROUND_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->groupBox, "color");
    animation2->setDuration(2000);
    animation2->setStartValue(QColor(0, 0, 0));
    animation2->setEndValue(QColor(240, 240, 240));

QSequentialAnimationGroup *group=new QSequentialAnimationGroup();
    group->addAnimation(animation2);
    group->start();
```

Comment: при этом ui->groupBox надо полагать обычный QGroupBox который вы в дизайнере кинули на форму?

Comment: Да. Я ведь правильно понимаю, что в этом коде к QGroupBox подключается новый параметр "color" которой я и буду изменять?

Comment: А как по вашему QGroupBox с вашей формы узнает что у него есть такой замечательный наследник, у которого есть проперти color, да еще и зачем-то будет им пользоваться? Если уж написали класс виджета, то и на форме размещайте AnimatedBackground

Comment: Я преобразовал свой groupbox размещенный на форме в AnimatedBackground, я правильно сделал? Анимация цвета не происходит, возможно в коде проблема.

Comment: При этом еще перестали отображаться дочерние элементы

Comment: У вас переопределен конструктор, при этом не вызывается родительский конструктор (при этом ваш конструктор пустой и зачем нужен непонятно)

Comment: Решил делать без формы и помогло. Унаследовал конструктор QGroupBox для моего класса и создал его объект. Все заработало